# Correct usage of "since"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is this statement:

> the letters have been troubling me since over a year

grammatically correct? Or should I instead use:

> ...for over a year

Comment: Since last year?

Comment: I do not want to specifically use last year..

Comment: [Relevant question about *since*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208622/has-changed-since-march-1-vs-changed-on-march-1)

Comment: Duplicate of '“since ages” or “for ages”?'.

Comment: Thanks for correcting 'an' #rathony and I have mentioned d full statement in d edit section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Since" is a word that is often mistranslated from other languages.  Be very cautious in its application.

In this case "for" is correct. "Over a year" is the sticking issue here.  It's not a time but a period.  "for" implies duration, i.e. covering a period of time. On the other hand, if you say "since last year" then you're picking a specific time and that would work.

Comment: Please explain the reason

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use only **for over a year**.
You could use **since** if it was **the last year**.

Comment: Please explain why so...

Comment: They use ''**for**'' to say how long has something been happening and ''**since**'' when the beginning of time period is known.